# Route debugger for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there a Route debugger for ASP.NET MVC out there? If so, where do I find it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Phil Haack has a [route debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) on [his blog](http://haacked.com).

Comment: I just hate when googling will give you an enlightened badge.

Answer (score 1):

codeplex has a [routing debugger visualizer](http://mvcroutevisualizer.codeplex.com/) for vs2010.

Answer (score 0):

All the prior information is **outdated** the configuration links no longer work for example.

Refer to Scott Hanselman's Blog for ***Glimpse***
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/IfYoureNotUsingGlimpseWithASPNETForDebuggingAndProfilingYoureMissingOut.aspx

Install with Nuget:

```
Install-Package Glimpse
```

or with MVC5 for example:

```
Install-Package Glimpse.MVC5
```

Then go to configuration page (can be different if in web config) Look for url Glimpse.axd.

Then go to the url to:

```
https://localhost:<your port>/Glimpse.axd
```

The documentation links may be out of date but the github repo has the most information:
https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse