# MVC RouteConfig allow /Controller/Action.html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC application and am using the standard routeconfig that routes /Controller/Action/Id

I want it to additionally capture `/Controller/Action.html` as the url and as well and point to `/controller/action` also.

I am using a jquery library that I have no control over, and a function requires a url that points to a webpage or an image. However, it doesn't appear to understand that ends without an extension(.html, .php etc) is a link to html and throws an error.

Edit: I tried as the commenter below suggested, and still can't seem to get it to work. Here is my route config.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("routeWithHtmlExtension",
            "{controller}/{action}.html",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

This Url works:

```
 http://localhost:14418/Album/Test
```

This one does not:

```
 http://localhost:14418/Album/Test.html
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331516/asp-net-mvc-routing-add-html-extension-to-routes

Answer (score 2):

In web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
...
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set up the following route, it will work:

```
routes.MapRoute("routeWithHtmlExtension",
    "{controller}/{action}.html",
    new {controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Comment: I understand how the default routing works, first goes to the controller then finds the matching action with matching params. I can get to /Home/Index from a default project, but after adding the code snippet above, I cant get to /Home/Index.html =/.

Comment: @user1308743 I'd install Phil Haack's Routedebugger and debug it if I were you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945027/any-url-routing-debugger-in-asp-net-mvc  I've tested the solution in a stock ASP.NET MVC project version 4 with the default 'internet application' set up, so I know it works.